# SignalR Ninject in Console Application (Self Hosted)

Tags: c#, signalr

I am trying to set up Ninject with SignalR in a console application but am getting a:

> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

My code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "http://localhost:8081/";
    var server = new Server(url);                        

    // Map the default hub url (/signalr)
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(Kernel);            
    server.MapHubs();

    // Start the server
    server.Start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it before creating the Server instance:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(Kernel);

    string url = "http://localhost:8081/";
    var server = new Server(url);                        

    // Map the default hub url (/signalr)
    server.MapHubs();

    // Start the server
    server.Start();
```

OR

Setup the dependency resolver on the server itself:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "http://localhost:8081/";
    var server = new Server(url, NinjectDependencyResolver(Kernel));

    server.MapHubs();

    // Start the server
    server.Start();
```

In the latter case, you won't be able to use GlobalHost for broadcasting but you can use the server directly to do the same thing.